# SQL Server 2008: Finding a value from a string

Tags: sql-server, select, dynamic, charindex

```
This might be a very simple select statement, here's my question.

I have a variable 
DECLARE @A varchar(128) --declaring variable
SET @A = 'sus_123456_R5_20140506'  --setting value
```

> I want to find the value after 'sus_' and before '*R5'
>       Also, the value in between is not of fixed length. So the function has to be dynamic.
>       However it always have sus* and _R5_date. That's constant.

```
SET @A = 'sus_129_R5_20150408

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING` in combination with `CHARINDEX`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@A,CHARINDEX('sus_',@A,0)+4,CHARINDEX('_R5',@A,0)-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this once using `SUBSTRING()` and `CHARINDEX()` FUNCTION

```
DECLARE @A varchar(128) --declaring variable
SET @A = 'sus_123456_R5_20140506'

select substring(@A,charindex('_',@A)+1,charindex('r5',@A)- (2+charindex('_',@A)))
```

Results in: `123456`

(OR) This one using `LEFT()`,`RIGHT()` and `CHARINDEX()` function.

```
DECLARE @A varchar(128) 
SET @A = 'sus_129_R5_20150408'
select right(left(@A,charindex('R5',@A) - 2),charindex('_',@A) - 1)
```

Results in: `129`

Read more about [String Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)